# Using a string variable for a math function in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm really new to Java, and I was working on a problem that asks the user their birthdate, then takes the input, subtracts it from the current year (manual input on the backend) and then works with said number to do a few things.

For the first math part of that, I was trying to use a string variable in a Java math function to no success.

Currently, my code is (including a small section of the prompt, for context):

```
// 2.  a. Skip a line, then prompt the user for the year
//            they were born.
//     b. Calculate and print the age the user will be this year.
//     c. Declare a constant for average life expectancy,
//            set its value to 78.7.
//     d. Print a message that tells the user the percentage
//            of their expected life they've lived.
//       Use the DecimalFormat class to format the percentage

  //double age;
  String year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What year were you born?");
  String age = 2015 - year;
```

I've also tried that last line as "age = 2015- year;"

What's the proper way to go about getting this to compile? NetBeans keeps shooting a "bad operand types for binary operator '-' " error

My background is only from C, where something similar to this would have worked.

If need be, I can post the full program, but other than this section none of it is relevant.

Comment: Something similar to this definitely would not work in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parseInt()` function to first convert a `String` into an `int`, perform the mathematical operation(s), and then convert `int` to `String`.

It is always safer to convert `String` into `int` / `float` for mathematical operations, as some mathematical operators are used for specific operation in `String`, for example: `+` is used for string concatenation by default in Java.

Code:

```
int _age = 2015 - Integer.parseInt(year);
String age = String.valueOf(_age);
```

You could also do this in one line,

```
String age = String.valueOf( 2015 - Integer.parseInt(year) );
```

Comment: If it helped you, say thanks by pressing that gray tick below the upvote-downvote counter to make it green! :)

Comment: Done and done! I'm a little new to the user side of stackoverflow, so I'm still navigating things. :)

Comment: Welcome to the community. The question that you asked was well-formatted and logical, especially for a newcomer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Haha, thank you, I appreciate it. I'm doing my best to use more technical terms rather than general terms, and it's definitely helping people understand me better, I've noticed. :D

Answer (score 1):

you need to do

```
String age=String.valueOf(2015-Integer.valueOf(year));
```

The '-' didnt work for you because you are trying to perform '-' on 2  string objects, but unlike `C` java doesnt support operator overloading. 
By default on String objects you can only use '+' operation for string concatenation

good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Both your solution and Shaurya Chats' have removed the compilation error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Subtract string from an int. It is not supported.
Cast year into an int before using it with integer.

```
int year =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What year were you born?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String year = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What year were you born?");
int dob = Integer.parseInt(year);
String age = Integer.toString(2015 - dob);
```